# How to hide navigationbar and statusbar in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I already know about the [Accompanist library](https://github.com/google/accompanist/tree/main/systemuicontroller) to change the color of navigation and status bar.

The goal is to hide them completely.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`SystemUiController` has a getter/setter method for system bar visibilities:

```
val systemUiController: SystemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()

systemUiController.isStatusBarVisible = false // Status bar
systemUiController.isNavigationBarVisible = false // Navigation bar
systemUiController.isSystemBarsVisible = false // Status & Navigation bars
```

Comment: anyway to achieve android sticky immersive with this one?

Comment: Haven't looked that much into that but I couldn't figure that out last time I tried.

Comment: WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window,window.decorView).apply { 
            if (isTrue) systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
        }

Comment: Don't forget to add -> implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:0.28.0"

Answer (score 8):

Since accompanist-systemuicontroller got deprecated, here is another solution.

With a disposable:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun HideSystemBars() {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        val window = context.findActivity()?.window ?: return@DisposableEffect onDispose {}
        val insetsController = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)

        insetsController.apply {
            hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars())
            hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars())
            systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
        }

        onDispose {
            insetsController.apply {
                show(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars())
                show(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars())
                systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_DEFAULT
            }
        }
    }
}

fun Context.findActivity(): Activity? {
    var context = this
    while (context is ContextWrapper) {
        if (context is Activity) return context
        context = context.baseContext
    }
    return null
}
```

Or without one:

```kotlin
val insetsController = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)

insetsController.apply {
    hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars())
    hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars())
    systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
}
```

Comment: best answer ,search it for long time

Answer (score 2):

> To Hide Statusbar for single Composable Screen

```
DisposableEffect(key1 = true){
    systemUiController.isStatusBarVisible = false // Status bar
    onDispose {
        systemUiController.isStatusBarVisible = true // Status bar
    }
}
```

> Also add this dependency

```
    implementation("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:0.31.2-alpha")
```

Comment: The accompanis library has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

**u can just do that in your MainActivity**

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me, you need to keep in mind that this is mixing up compose code with code from the traditional system. I'm preferring to use only one UI concept as long as its possible.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but sometimes we can use code from the traditional system. i can't see a problem in this case.

Comment: @DanielWeidensdörfer  It's not clear that Compose is intended to take over things this. It certainly isn't in control of drawing the status / nav bars, so not sure why we'd assume it should be in control of showing or hiding them. The other thing is, if Compose was intended to do this, why doesn't it? The `SystemUiController` library linked above isn't part of Compose it's ultimately just a wrapper around using either `WindowInsert` or `DecorView.systemUiVisibility`.

Answer (score 0):

Also add `LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES` for hide notch

```
val window = (view.context as Activity).window
val layoutParams = window.attributes

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
  layoutParams.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES
}
window.attributes = layoutParams
```

Add in composable so it has padding, preferable in `TopAppBar`

```
modifier = Modifier.windowInsetsPadding(WindowInsets.displayCutout)
```