# How to implement transparent status bar in Jetpack Compose Android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-statusbar, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I want to implement transparent status bar in jetpack compose.

I have integrated the Accompanist library for this but it has no transparent effect on status bar.

```
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:0.18.0"

// Remember a SystemUiController
val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
val useDarkIcons = !isSystemInDarkTheme()

DisposableEffect(systemUiController, useDarkIcons) {
    // Update all of the system bar colors to be transparent, and use
    // dark icons if we're in light theme
    systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(
        color = Color.Transparent,
        darkIcons = useDarkIcons
    )

    // setStatusBarColor() and setNavigationBarColor() also exist

    onDispose {}
}
```

Tried this as well, but it has problem with the gesture navigation

```
val view = LocalView.current
if (!view.isInEditMode) {
SideEffect {
  val window = (view.context as Activity).window
  val insets = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view)
  window.statusBarColor = Color.Transparent.toArgb() // choose a status bar color
  window.navigationBarColor = Color.Transparent.toArgb() // choose a navigation bar color
  insets.isAppearanceLightStatusBars = !useDarkTheme
  insets.isAppearanceLightNavigationBars = !useDarkTheme
 }
}
```

Kindly suggest a better solution for the transparent status bar.

[image]

Comment: Did you apply `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)`?

Comment: Yes, This will have an impact on gesture navigation, which is why don't want to go with this approach.

Comment: Can you post a screen?

Comment: updated the question, please check.

Comment: do you have any updates about this post?

Comment: try updating to latest ```androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0``` and the use ```enableEdgeToEdge()``` Features its very easy and customizable

Answer (score 5):

In Jetpack Compose you can make the status bar translucent using the new Edge-To-Edge API since accompanist-systemuicontroller is deprecated.

First, go to your Theme.kt and remove the view part from it (the following part):

```
// Remove this part
val view = LocalView.current
    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            val window = (view.context as Activity).window
            window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.primary.toArgb()
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = darkTheme
        }
    }
```

Second, open your activity if it is MainActivity.kt or anything else and enable edge-to-edge on it, as following:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        enableEdgeToEdge() // Add this
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // Your composables ...
    }
}
```

Now you can run and see the status bar became translucent.

But here is a tip, by default, calling enableEdgeToEdge() automatically adjusts the system bar style to be transparent and dynamically adapts the icon & text colors based on the device’s current theme (white for dark mode, black for light mode).

So you can control the icon & text colors like this:

```
    // For dark (black) colors
    enableEdgeToEdge(
        statusBarStyle = SystemBarStyle.dark(
            android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT,
        )
    )


    // For light (white) colors
    enableEdgeToEdge(
        statusBarStyle = SystemBarStyle.light(
            android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT,
            android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT
        )
    )
```

So handle the colors as you needed, leave it default to system or make it light or dark based on your use case.

Answer (score 3):

You have to enable full-screen mode to draw under statusbar:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
}
```

And you can use `WindowInsets` to avoid drawing under "System gestures":

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(view) { view, windowInsets ->
   val insets = windowInsets.getInsets(
       WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemGestures()
   )
   view.updatePadding(
       insets.left, 
       insets.top, 
       insets.right, 
       insets.bottom
   )
   WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED
}
```

For more information, look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/edge-to-edge)

Comment: Tried this, but this has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

1. Call `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)` in `Activity.onCreate`. This call requests that your app display behind the system UI. Your app will then be in control of how those insets are used to adjust the UI.
2. Set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in your Activity's AndroidManifest.xml entry. This setting allows your app to receive the size of the software IME as insets, which you can use to pad and lay out content appropriately when the IME appears and disappears in your app.

3. Adjust the color of the system bars and icons in your app's theme to be transparent:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.Material.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!--Other app theme properties-->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Source and more details: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/insets

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't gotten a solution to this you can use the accompanist library
reference already answered below [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69689196/12761938)

Answer (score 0):

> Following @Abanoub Samir's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77938124/8460768) (using `enableEdgeToEdge()`
> with local view removed) will draw the app content below the status
> bar as shown below.
>
> [image]
>
> To resolve this you can use `Modifier.statusBarsPadding()` in your `@Composable` component.

**The solution**

The recommended way to do this without `enableEdgeToEdge` is in `Theme.kt` inside `SideEffect` leveraging [`WindowInsetsControllerCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/WindowInsetsControllerCompat). Default jetpack compose project template does have this `SideEffect` implemented. So, we can edit that section as shown below:

```
val view = LocalView.current
if (!view.isInEditMode) {
    SideEffect {
        val window = (view.context as Activity).window
        val insetsController = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view)
        window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.background.toArgb()
        window.navigationBarColor = colorScheme.background.toArgb()
        insetsController.isAppearanceLightStatusBars = !darkTheme
        insetsController.isAppearanceLightNavigationBars = !darkTheme
    }
}
```

This will produce the output as shown below:

[image: light mode] [image: dark mode]

Hope this will be helpful

Answer (score -1):

**Try This**

Add the below line to your Theme

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

after adding this line to the theme set this theme in your activity in which you want to set a transparent status bar

Your activity/container layout you wish to have a transparent status bar needs this property set:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

add in activity root layout

Comment: also, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29311321/7760687)

Comment: I want to implement this with Jetpack compose.